# Different labels on main page

Tags: bug, recent-activity

There's two questions on main page, both mention authors, but only one of them has label "asked", why?

[image]

Links to questions:

1. [Birthday notifications on Google Calendar](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113922/birthday-notifications-on-google-calendar)
2. [How to configure Google Calendar to parse an Event start time like it did in the past](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113921/how-to-configure-google-calendar-to-parse-an-event-start-time-like-it-did-in-the)

---

**Edit:**

There's another one migrated question, but it displayed on main page even without author's name:

[image]

But inside, it has link to author's profile, maybe something wrong because it has [untagged](/questions/tagged/untagged) tag:

[image]

Link to question: [Reorder slides in a NextCloud presenation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114527/reorder-slides-in-a-nextcloud-presenation)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second question was migrated from Super User.

I think this confuses the code that decides which of asked/answered/modified to display on the home page.

It either needs to say "migrated" or find out the most recent of the "normal" changes and display that.